# ¿Como acceder a la variable que esta en js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Hola buen día me serviría de mucho que me ayudaran con lo siguiente:

```
'<td idpatente ="'+elem.id_mantencion_tractos_marca+'">'+'<button type="button" name="codigo" id="'+elem.id_mantencion_tractos_marca+'" class="btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MostrarFactura" onclick=Modal('+elem.id_mantencion_tractos_marca+')>VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button> '+'</td>'+

<script>    
var aux='';
    function Modal(argument) {
        aux=argument;
   }    
console.log(aux);
</script>


    <div class="modal fade" id="MostrarFactura" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">VISUALIZACION FACTURA MANTENCION</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo" id="codigo" > 



 <?php 

  ?>

     

 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tengo ese botón en una tabla. Al momento de presionarlo se va al script de la función Moda(argument); El id del botón lo necesito. Pero quiero que sea global. Porque lo voy a necesitar para una consulta. Que va a estar en el modal.

Comment: Desde el momento en que la defines con `var` ya es global y puedes acceder a ella, pero no se modifica porque no estás ejecutando la función. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar un poco más de contexto como dónde (y cuándo) planeas realizar cambios y dónde (y cuando) quieres que se reflejen.

Comment: Explica cuál es el problema y qué es lo que quieres hacer en realidad, pues el código que muestras no tiene ningún sentido. La variable `aux` en ese contexto es accesible y se imprimirá en el `console.log`. En cuanto a la  función, no explicas nada sobre ella. Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: @Triby hay agregue un comentario. Lo que quiero es que la variable aux pueda verse en la consola pero fuera de la función. Porque al ejecutarla me aparece que la variable aux esta indefinida. Saludos

Comment: @A.Cedano Tengo ese botón en una tabla. Al momento de presionarlo se va al script de la función Moda(argument); El id del botón lo necesito. Pero quiero que sea global. Porque lo voy a necesitar para una consulta.

Comment: @keane1991, acabo de editar tu pregunta para comprobar el comportamiento y, como ves, no hay errores, por eso es que necesitamos saber dónde (parte del código) y cuándo (antes de incluir otro archivo, antes o después de ejecutar función, etc.).

Comment: @Triby Tengo ese botón en una tabla. Al momento de presionarlo se va al script de la función Moda(argument); El id del botón lo necesito. Pero quiero que sea global. Porque lo voy a necesitar para una consulta. Que va a estar en el modal.

Comment: ¿A qué botón te refieres, al que está dentro de este elemento: `<td idpatente ...`? Deberías basar tu código Javascript en escucha de eventos, las funciones in-line son una mala práctica, y hacen pensar todo de una manera complicada. Por ejemplo, en ese contexto NO necesitas pasar en parámetro el valor que tenga el botón en su id, lo puedes obtener mediante la escucha de eventos, simplificando el código.

Comment: @keane1991, en lugar de guardar el ID del botón en una variable, podrías ponerlo como atributo de un elemento en la ventana modal, tal vez como valor de un campo oculto y así puedes tenerlo disponible justo donde lo necesitas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente creo que **estás sub-estimando a Javascript** y eso te lleva a aplicar malas prácticas y podría llevarte a escribir un código rocambolesco para lograr algo simple.

Tú puedes sustituir tu función `Modal()` puesta in-line en cada botón, lo cual es una mala práctica, por la **escucha de eventos**. Bastaría con alcanzar los elementos por su tipo (`button`)  y por su clase (`MostrarFactura`) y obtener todo lo demás (en este caso el id), mediante la escucha de eventos.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo, verás que he quitado esto de todos los botones: `onclick=Modal('+elem.id_mantencion_tractos_marca+')` por lo ya dicho, no es necesario, y es una pésima práctica hacer esto. Verás con simplemente con `e.target.id` obtienes el id, si implementas adecuadamente escucha de eventos.

```js
/*
  Alcanza todos los botones
  que tengan la clase MostrarFactura
  */
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button.MostrarFactura");

/*
  Asignas un click listener a todos esos botones
  desarrollando dentro la lógica que te interese,
  obtener su id lo que sea ...
  No sub-estimes la potencia de Javascript,
  aplicando un poco de lógica puedes simplificar situaciones complejas
  como alcanzar elementos adyacentes, etc
  */

allButtons.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }))
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td idpatente="1"><button type="button" name="codigo" id="1" class="btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MostrarFactura">VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td idpatente="2"><button type="button" name="codigo" id="2" class="btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MostrarFactura">VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td idpatente="3"><button type="button" name="codigo" id="3" class="btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MostrarFactura">VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Dado que usar ids numéricos no es recomendable, en caso de necesitar números, puedes usar atributos de datos, u otra propiedad del elemento (por ejemplo la propiedad `value`) para guardar dichos datos en caso de ser numéricos.

He aquí un ejemplo basado en atributos de datos:

```js
/*
  Alcanza todos los botones
  que tengan la clase MostrarFactura
  */
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button.MostrarFactura");

/*
  Asignas un click listener a todos esos botones
  desarrollando dentro la lógica que te interese,
  obtener su id lo que sea ...
  No sub-estimes la potencia de Javascript,
  aplicando un poco de lógica puedes simplificar situaciones complejas
  como alcanzar elementos adyacentes, etc
  */

allButtons.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let dataSet=e.target.dataset;
    console.log(`Has pulsado el botón ${e.target.id} y el valor de su data-id es ${dataSet.id}`);
  }))
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td idpatente="1"><button type="button" name="codigo" id="btn1" data-id="1" class="btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MostrarFactura">VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td idpatente="2"><button type="button" name="codigo" id="btn2" data-id="2" class="btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MostrarFactura">VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td idpatente="3"><button type="button" name="codigo" id="btn3" data-id="3" class="btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MostrarFactura">VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: También se considera mala práctica usar ID numérico, se recomienda que comience con una letra. [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id#sect1). Supongo que sería mejor usar atributos de datos, como `data-id`.

Comment: Tienes razón @Triby ahora edito y pongo un ejemplo con atributos de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo un dilema estimado en el cod si me puedes guiar plis https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/521060/al-momento-de-seleccionar-un-dato-del-select-como-puedo-llenar-el-input-que-est ese es el link

Comment: @A.Cedano necesito de su ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/521060/al-momento-de-seleccionar-un-dato-del-select-como-puedo-llenar-el-input-que-est